# Why my ProgressBar looks different in different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, spinner

I used `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"` to create the spinning `ProgressBar`.
Not sure why in different layout XML it behaves differently(I am using the same device).
It shows as a blue spinning circle and a circle of gray dots. I want to use the blue spinning circle in all my pages..

please advise!

Sorry that I don't have the reputation to upload pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its dependent on background color of the layout. once put all layouts background color to black or some unique color. Then it will look uniquely.

If you want to put as unique for all pages the solution is:

Maintain same background color for all views

Otherwise use custom progress bar.

Comment: Thanks man! I changed the theme colour into default one instead of @android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen  and the blue progressbar appears! But I still need to figure out how to invoke the blue progressbar with the original theme though..maybe there is a way..maybe i have to use custom progress bar then